# What does the '1 mean when I GetType().Name on a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

What does the '1 mean when I GetType().Name on a generic type?  Just curious...  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that the type takes in 1 generic type argument.

If you're wondering why it's necessary, it's to distinguish different types based on name alone, rather than based on other attributes (like how many type arguments it takes).

Comment: Yup.
(Here's some more text to make the answer longer so I can actually answer you.) :)

Comment: @Mike To illustrate, check these strings: `typeof(Action).Name`, `typeof(Action).ToString()`, `typeof(Action<>).Name`, `typeof(Action<>).ToString()`, `typeof(Action<,>).Name`, `typeof(Action<,>).ToString()`, `typeof(Action<,,>).Name`, `typeof(Action<,,>).ToString()`, and so on. (Result (the last two): ``"Action`3"`` and ``"System.Action`3[T1,T2,T3]"``)