# Why is the source of the List<T> class named List'1.cs?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

When I press Ctrl and click on List in VS2010, List'1.cs file is opened, and the file contains the method headers and the summary comments,

[image]

The question is, why thy didn't name that file List(T).cs or List{T}.cs or List[T].cs?
Why the naming convention List'1.cs, is that standard?

Comment: Why not? That's how IL signifies generics.

Comment: Also worth checking - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558141/what-does-the-1-mean-when-i-gettype-name-on-a-generic-type

Comment: Intermediate Language. What .NET languages get compiled into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the CLR, that's the default way to annotate generic types. List`1 means that this class has one generic type parameter. The brackets are just a C# thing, also they are not valid as file names.

Answer (score 3):

Found in the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) *Section 10.7.2 Type names and arity coding* (the quote is a little malformed):

> CLS-compliant generic type names are encoded using the format
>   ―name[`arity]‖ , where […] indicates that the grave accent character
>   ―`‖ and arity together are optional. The encoded name shall follow
>   these rules:
>
> 1. name shall be an ID (see Partition II) that does not contain the ―`‖ character.
> 2. arity is specified as an unsigned decimal number without leading zeros or spaces.
> 3. For a normal generic type, arity is the number of type parameters declared on the type.
> 4. For a nested generic type, arity is the number of newly introduced type parameters.

If you couple this with the `<>` characters not being valid for Windows file names, it makes some sense why they applied the naming convention to the file name as well. The ` symbol is a valid Windows file name character.

Comment: @downvoter Fly-by downvoting, got to love it.

Comment: @TheOtherDownvoter 2 downvotes and no explanation?

Answer (score 1):

The naming is standard for generic types.